# C# - Open Forms With Parameters

Tags: c#, forms

I am working on a Customized Main Menu for a game (COD MW2)
so I need to know how when somebody clicks on an item (`labe or textbox) it will call another form that will contain some custom parameters, without making a form for each Label/textbox !

It's kinda like the Properties Window in Visual Studio! When I select a label you choose the parameters and stuff.

If you didn't understood what I mean please tell me :)

I've already tried to do this but I failed :/

**EDIT:**

I just found how to do it but i still don't know how to send the info back to the Form1 and Reload The Form1 .... help me please :))

Comment: You might want to give a more exact example (including specific buttons/labels/text boxes) for you Visual Studio example. It's not very clear as-is what behavior you want to copy from the "Properties Window"

Comment: can you show your code how you tried to solve this?

Comment: well , i didnt started my project yet , but this is the idea : 
when somebody Clicks on a Label OR a textbox , the Form2 will show with some parameters , like when i click on a label1 the Form2 will popup with label1's text in a textbox and i can change it ... 
u got it ?

Comment: "I've already tried to do this but I failed" then you say "I didn't start my project yet" so which is it?

Comment: i tried some codes from other guys ... i didnt did anythin yet , because this is the heart of the project .. i need this to start it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**  **Open Forms With Parameters**

Form1:

```
private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2(label1);
            f2.Show();
            f2.textBox1.Text = label1.Text;
        }
```

Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        Label x;
        public Form2(Label y)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            x = y;
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            x.Text = textBox1.Text;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can u check my Comment up there ? i just explained it more i think :/

Comment: Respect ! Thats Just What i was needing ! but i need to add more things ! thank you :)

Comment: Hey , and how Can i send the Info Back to The Form1 and edit The text in Form1 to the Value that user typed in Form2 ? ty